# Descending digit sequences

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

#### Introduction

As an example, let's take the number `7`. We then duplicate this and place 7 spaces in between. We get this:

```
7_______7
```

After that, we are going to decrease the number, until there are no spaces left. We get the following for the number 7:

```
7_______7    
 6543210
```

Then, we just merge the two of them, so:

```
7_______7    
 6543210  becomes

765432107
```

This will be out output for **N = 7**.

Looks easy, right? Now let's take **N = 12**. We again insert 12 spaces between the two numbers, which gives us:

```
12____________12
```

Then we start the decrement:

```
12____________12
  111098765432
```

And this finally gives us:

```
1211109876543212
```

**As you can see, the descending part ends at 2, *not* at 0**.

#### Task

Given an integer, **greater than 1**, output the descending sequence as shown above.

#### Test cases

```
Input   Output

2       2102
3       32103
4       432104
5       5432105
6       65432106
7       765432107
8       8765432108
9       98765432109
10      10987654321010
11      111098765432111
12      1211109876543212
13      13121110987654313
14      141312111098765414
15      1514131211109876515
20      201918171615141312111020
99      9998979695949392919089888786858483828180797877767574737271706968676665646362616059585756555453525150499
100     1009998979695949392919089888786858483828180797877767574737271706968676665646362616059585756555453525150100
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the fewest number of bytes wins!

Comment: The inner space must be filled with whole numbers or we should chop numbers if needed? There is not a test case about that (for instance 99)

Comment: @edc65 You should chop the numbers if needed. I have added 99 as a test case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## CJam, <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

```
q4*~,W%s<\
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q4*~%2CW%25s%3C%5C&input=12%0A) Assumes there is a trailing newline in the input. (Thanks to @jimmy23013 for saving a byte.)

#### Explanation

At the end of each line is what the stack looks like at that point (using `4` as an example).

```
q4*  e# Push input x 4 times, separated by newlines. ["4\n4\n4\n4\n"]
~    e# Evaluate, separating the 4's and converting them to numbers. [4 4 4 4]
,W%  e# Take the range of x and reverse it. [4 4 4 [3 2 1 0]]
s<   e# Cast to string and take the first x characters. [4 4 "3210"]
\    e# Swap the top two to get the final result. [4 "3210" 4]
```

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, 30 bytes

```julia
n->"$n"join(n-1:-1:0)[1:n]"$n"
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns a string. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We construct and join the descending sequence from *n*-1 to 0, and take the first *n* characters from the resulting string. We prepend and append this with the input as a string.

[Verify all test cases online](http://goo.gl/Dcb1XH)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>55</s> 52 bytes

```
n=>n+[...Array(m=n)].map(_=>--m).join``.slice(0,n)+n
```

Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @WashingtonGuedes.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Bah, I never seem to get to use `.keys()`.

Comment: `.keys()` is like `.reduce`. The right tool for the job, but you always find something that can do better in that particular case

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
s=show
f n=s n++take n(s=<<[n-1,n-2..])++s n
```

Usage example: `f 14` -> `"141312111098765414"`.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>82</s> <s>72</s> <s>58</s> 53 bytes

```python
lambda x:`x`+''.join(map(str,range(x)[::-1]))[:x]+`x`
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/BqlF/3)

Thanks to @Alex for teaching me that `repr(x)` = `` `x` `` saving me a bunch of bytes!

Answer (score 3):

### Pyth, 11 bytes

```
++Q<jk_UQQQ
```

Two alternative versions, which are all also 11 bytes (*sigh*):

```
s[Q<jk_UQQQ
pQp<jk_UQQQ
```

```
  Q           the input
       UQ     [0, 1, ..., input-2, input-1]
      _       reverse
    jk        join on empty string
   <     Q    first (input) characters
          Q   the input again
++            concatenate everything so it prints on one line
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2BQ%3Cjk_UQQQ&input=12&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, 10 bytes

```
Ȯ’r0DFḣ³Ḍ³
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=yK7igJlyMERG4bijwrPhuIzCsw&input=&args=MTAw)

#### How it works

```
Ȯ’r0DFḣ³Ḍ³  Main link. Input: n

Ȯ           Print n.
 ’          Decrement to yield n - 1.
  r0        Create a range from n - 1 to 0.
    D       Convert each integer to base 10 (array of decimal digits).
     F      Flatten the resulting array.
      ḣ³    Keep the first n elements.
        Ḍ   Convert from base 10 to integer.
         ³  Print the integer and set the return value to n.
            (implicit) Print the return value.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 13 bytes

```
U+Uo w ¬¯U +U
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VStVbyB3IKyvVSArVQ==&input=MTAw)

#### How it works

```
               // Implicit: U = input integer
  Uo           // Create the range [0..U).
     w         // Reverse.
       ¬       // Join.
        ¯U     // Slice to the first U chars.
U+         +U  // Append U on either end.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 98 <strike>110</strike>

Longest answer so far :-/

```
.+
$&;$&$*:
+`:(:+)$
$& $1
 (:)*
$#1
\d+$
$&0 $&0
T`d`,`\d+$
+`:(.*),
$1
+`. ,
 
(.+);(.*) 
$1$2$1
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCY7JCYkKjoKK2A6KDorKSQKJCYgJDEKICg6KSoKJCMxClxkKyQKJCYwICQmMApUYGRgLGBcZCskCitgOiguKiksCiQxCitgLiAsCiAKKC4rKTsoLiopIAokMSQyJDE&input=MTI)

Comment: [You can beat Java!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74325/7311)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 15 bytes

```
VG:qPVXvG:)GVhh
```

*EDIT (May 20, 2016) The code in the link uses `Xz` instead of `Xv`, owing to recent changes in the language.*

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Vkc6cVBWWHpHOilHVmho&input=MTAw)

```
V                 % input n. Convert to string
 G:               % range [1,2,...,n]
   qP             % convert into [n-1,n-2,...,0]
     VXv          % convert to string, no spaces
        G:)       % take first n characters only
           GV     % push input as a string, again
             hh   % concat horizontally twice
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pure Bash, 49

```bash
eval printf -va %s {$[$1-1]..0}
echo $1${a::$1}$1
```

Or:

## Bash + coreutils, 48

```bash
echo $1$(seq $[$1-1] -1 0|tr -d \\n|head -c$1)$1
```

Comment: I'm not certain these are evaluating the range properly. Upon testing both print only half of the range. ie for $1=90, the range is only down to 45.
My effort was "
for i in $(eval echo {$1..0});do echo -n $i;done;echo $1"

Comment: @rcjohnson I think that is the required behaviour.  What do you expect the output to be for N=90?

Comment: @rcjohnson e.g. for N=12, the output should be `12`, then the first 12 chars of `11..0` (or `111098765432`), and then finally `12`

Comment: Well upon re-reading the description I see that you are correct. The problem states "spaces" not integers.

Comment: @rcjohnson Yes, I think the "spaces" part only applies to intermediate steps.  The final output should be just a string of digits.

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy, 35 bytes

Since Vitsy isn't aware of how to make strings out of numbers, I implemented finding the length of the number in decimal places in the second line.

```
V0VVNHVv[XDN1mv$-DvD);]VN
1a/+aL_1+
```

Explanation:

```
V0VVNHVv[XDN1mv$-DvD);]VN
V                          Save the input as a global final variable.
 0V                        Push 0, push input.
   VN                      Output the input.
     H                     Push the range 0...intput.
      Vv                   Push the input, then save it as a temp variable.
        [             ]    Do the stuff in brackets infinitely or until exited.
         X                 Remove the top item of the stack.
          DN               Duplicate, then pop as output.
            1m             Calls the first line index, retrieving length.
              v            Pop the temp var and push it to the stack.
               $           Switch the top two items of the stack. 
                -          Subtract them.
                 Dv        Duplicate, then pop one as a temp var.
                   D);     If it's zero, exit the loop.
                       VN  Output the global var.

1a/+aL_1+
1a/+       Add .1. This makes sure we don't throw errors on input 0.
    a      Push ten.
     L     Pop the top item as n, push the log base n of second to top.
      _    Make it an int.
       1+  Add 1.
```

[Try it Online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=VjBWVk5IVnZbWEROMW12JC1EdkQpO11WTgoxYS8rYUxfMSs&input=&args=MTAw)

Verbose mode for lols:

```
save top as permanent variable;
push 0;
save top as permanent variable;
save top as permanent variable;
output top as number;
push all ints between second to top and top;
save top as permanent variable;
save top as temporary variable;
begin recursive area;
remove top;
duplicate top item;
output top as number;
push 1;
goto top method;
save top as temporary variable;
switch the top two items;
subtract top two;
duplicate top item;
save top as temporary variable;
duplicate top item;
if (int) top is not 0;
generic exit;
end recursive area;
save top as permanent variable;
output top as number;
:push 1;
push 10;
divide top two;
add top two;
push 10;
push ln(top);
replace top with int(top);
push 1;
add top two;
```

Comment: Looks like verbose mode is wrong in its definition of `L`, fixing that now (won't update the question though).

Comment: Just curious, how do you prevent the method from being executed at the end of the program? Is the newline character a signal to return/exit the program?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Imagine that the first line of every Vitsy program is the "main" method, and all other lines are `public static void` methods. The main ends the program when it is finished. As for how it does this, the instructions are held in a type `ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>`, where each line is a `String[]`. Every method is split at the newline by how the file is loaded, causing the main method to be separated from all other methods.

Comment: That explains why three levels are needed. So `String`s are instructions, `String[]`s are methods (first one is main method), and `ArrayList<String[]>`s are classes (first one is main class), correct?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 That's all correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 63 bytes

```
.+
$0,y$0$*y$0$*x
x
$'_
(x)*_
$#1
+`(y+)y(.)
$2$1
,(\d+).*
$1$`
```

There is still quite some room for golfing...

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJDAseSQwJCp5JDAkKngKeAokJ18KKHgpKl8KJCMxCitgKHkrKXkoLikKJDIkMQosKFxkKyl5LioKJDEkYA&input=MTI)

Comment: Hm, I'm considering to make the `$0` in `$0$*` optional as well, when the preceding token is a literal which is not a number (as your `y`s are)... seeing this I might actually implement that.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I thought that was the new feature but turned out not really. :)

Comment: No, currently that only works at the beginning of the substitution. That said, maybe you can switch the roles of the first and last number to make use of that?

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 93 bytes

```
String x(int v){String o=""+v;for(int i=v-1,c=o.length();o.length()-c<v;i--)o+=i;return o+v;}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 41 bytes

```
->n{[n]*2*(r=0...n).to_a.reverse.join[r]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way 1.6.5](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
I'::%{K£BCH=}<ΩHG<+<;+!
```

---

#### Explanation

```
I                        ` empty the stack
 '::                     ` push 3 copies of the input
    %{K£BCH=}            ` dump digits of reversed range(n) as strings [n-1...0]
             <ΩHG<+<;+   ` select the first nth digits and pad them with n
                      !  ` output
```

---

#### Usage

```
$ ./mw <path-to-code> -i <input-integer>
```

Comment: What encoding does Milky Way use?

Comment: Uhhh.. UTF-8, I think haha. @AandN

Comment: I got [this error](http://pastebin.com/XunhmVcx) (yes, I'm a Windows scumbag :p) while trying to run this. I pasted this: `I'::%{K£BCH=}<OHG<+<;+!` into an UTF-8 encoded file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/i5x715b85t12x9u/descending-digits.mwg?dl=1) to the file I'm using. @AandN

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 31 bytes

```perl6
{$_~([R~] ^$_).substr(0,$_)~$_}
```

```perl6
{
  $_ # input
  ~  # string concatenated with
  ([R~] ^$_)    # all numbers up to and excluding the input concatenated in reverse
  .substr(0,$_) # but use only up to the input number of characters
  ~
  $_
}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
for 2,3,7,12,100 {
  say {$_~([R~] ^$_).substr(0,$_)~$_}( $_ )
}
```

```
2102
32103
765432107
1211109876543212
1009998979695949392919089888786858483828180797877767574737271706968676665646362616059585756555453525150100
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 43 + 2 = 45 bytes

I'm happy that I didn't used `reverse` and neither `substr`:

```
"@{[1-$_..0]}"=~s.\D..gr=~/.{$_}/;$_.=$&.$_
```

Requires the `-pl` flags.

```
$ perl -ple'"@{[1-$_..0]}"=~s.\D..gr=~/.{$_}/;$_.=$&.$_' <<< 12
1211109876543212
```

How it works:

```
                                            # '-p' read first line into `$_` and
                                            # auto print at the end
"@{[1-$_..0]}"                              # Create a list from -1-n..0 and
                                            # join it on space. This becomes:
                                            #   "-11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0"
              =~s.\D..gr                    # Remove all but digits:
                                            #   "11109876543210"
                        =~/.{$_}/;          # Match the n first characters from
                                            # the generated string
                                  $_.=$&.$_ # Append the match and the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>130</s> 125 bytes

```
#define p(x) printf("%i",x);
i,y,h;f(x){for(i=y=x;(i-=h)>=0;){p(y--)h=floor(log10(y))+1;}if(i+=h)p(h=floor(y/pow(10,i)))p(x)}
```

Ungolfed version (with explanation):

```
#define p(x) printf("%i",x);     // alias to print an integer
i,y,h;                           // helper variables
f(x){                            // function takes an integer x as arg
    for(i=y=x;(i-=h)>=0;){       // i -> the remaining space
                                 // y -> the current descending number
        p(y--)                   // print y (at first y==x)
        h=floor(log10(y))+1;     // h -> the number of digits in y-1
    }                            // do it until there is no more empty space
    if(i+=h)                     // if needs to chop the last number
        p(h=floor(y/pow(10,i)))  // chop and print (implicitly cast of double to int)
    p(x)                         // print x at the end
}                                // end function
```

The implicitly cast from double to int in `h=floor(...)` allowed the use of `#define p(x)` saving 5 bytes.

[Test on ideone.](http://ideone.com/daQou1)

Answer (score 1):

**R, 67 bytes (as function)**

```
# usage example : f(7)
f=function(i)cat(i,substr(paste((i-1):0,collapse=''),1,i),i,sep='')
```

**R, 63 bytes (input from STDIN)**

```
i=scan();cat(i,substr(paste((i-1):0,collapse=''),1,i),i,sep='')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Brainfuck, 265 Bytes

This is only going to work with numbers < 10

Try the golfed version [here](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#PiwtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS1bLT4rPis8PF0+PlstPDwrPj5dPFtbLT4rPis8PF0+PlstPDwrPj5dPC1dPFs8XT5bPls+XT4rPDxbPF0+LV0+WysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy4+XSsrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy4+KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLgoK):

```
>,------------------------------------------------[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<[[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<-]<[<]>[>[>]>+<<[<]>-]>[++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>]++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

Ungolfed. Try it [here](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#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):

```
>
,
---------- Convert to base 10
----------
----------
----------
-------- 


[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<

Fill up the grid
[
[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>] //duplicate number like [5][0] -> [5][5]
<-
]

<[<]> Go to cell 1
[

>[>] Scan for zero
> Move one more
+ Add one
<< Move two back
[<] Scan for zero
> Move one forward
- Subtract One
]

> Move one forward into actual numbers
[
++++++++++ Convert to ascii
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++
.
>
]
++++++++++ Convert to ascii
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++
.
>
++++++++++ Convert to ascii
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++
.
```

Comment: `,>>++++++[<++++++++>-]<[-<->]<` This can subtract 48 with shorter code length

Comment: [This is way shorter](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LFstPis+Kzw8XT4+Pj4rKysrKytbPCsrKysrKysrPi1dPFstPC0+XTwrWysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLV0uPC4=).

Comment: [This is even shorter.](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LFstPis+Kz4rPDw8XT4+Pj4+KysrKysrWy08KysrKysrKys+XTxbLTwtPl08K1s8Li0+LV08PC4=)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 45 bytes

```powershell
param($a)"$a$(($a-1)..0-join''|% su* 0 $a)$a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9vyCxKDFXQyVRU0klUUUDyNA11NTTM9DNys/MU1evUVUoLtVSMFAAKlBJVPpfy8WlppKmYGn5HwA)

### Explanation

```powershell
($a-1)..0-join''|% su* 0 $a     # builds an array from a-1 to 0, joins them with no separators 
                                  # and takes the `a` first chars

"$a ... $a"                       # surrounds the result with the parameter `a`
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ḶUDFṁ;D;@DḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4bi2VURG4bmBO0Q7QEThuIz/MTXhuIogOyAyMCw5OSwxMDAgw4figqwgWf8)

There is also [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2hLm4PdzZmOegk/Dc0fbijS8FawchAx9JSx9DAQOFw@6OmNQqR/wE) kinda cheaty 9 byter, which only works due to how the `Y` command in the Footer works, so I'm not counting that.

Jelly's dislike of strings really hurts it here, and CJam's stack is just helpful enough to beat Jelly.

### How it works

```
ḶUDFṁ;D;@DḌ - Main link. Takes n on the left
Ḷ           - [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]
 U          - [n-1, n-2, ..., 1, 0]
  D         - Convert each to digits
   F        - Flatten
    ṁ       - Take the first n
     ;D     - Append the digits of n
       ;@D  - Prepend the digits of n
          Ḍ - Convert from a list of digits to a number
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
Î<ŸRJ¹£¹.ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9vc2FiaWX//8OOPMW4UkrCucKjwrkuw7j//zc)

```
Î<ŸRJ¹£¹.ø  # full program
        .ø  # surround...
      £     # first...
     ¹      # input...
      £     # chars of...
    J       # joined elements of...
  Ÿ         # [...
Î           # 0 ... input...
 <          # minus 1
  Ÿ         # ]...
   R        # reversed...
        .ø  # with...
     ¹      # input
            # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>9 8</s></sup> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
îσQçφ╠♦
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8ce55187edcc04&i=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13&m=2)

-1 byte from recursive.

### Explanation (Unpacked)

```
rr$x%sy|S
r         range 0..n-1
 r        reversed 
  $       converted to string
   x(     take n characters
     y    push n as string from register y
      |S  prepend and append it to the range
           implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 40 bytes

```perl
print$_,("@{[1-$_..0]}"=~/\d/g)[0..$_-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCVeR0PJoTraUFclXk/PILZWybZOPyZFP10z2kBPTyVe1zD2/39Do3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)